# Updated document ID's in elastic search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am currently using elastic search and Nest to update documents using `UpdateByQueryAsync`. Is there a way to get the ID's of all the documents that got updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like it, since the underlying [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) doesn't respond with them, just the number of updates.